# Load nib with NSWindowController don't have effect

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, nswindowcontroller

In my app i have Preferences window. To load this window i use this code

```
- (IBAction)showPrefWindow:(id)sender {

    NSWindowController * windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PrefWindow"];
    [windowController window];
}
```

but this is haven't effect (preferences window don't open).

When i use Xcode 4.1 DP1 this code work. Now i upgrade Xcode to 4.2 and code not work.

Where may be problem?
Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried calling "[[windowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:windowController];"?

Comment: then your window does not exist, you sure "PrefWindow.xib" exists in your project?